# Selenium: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm attempting to create an automated login script to netflix website: https://www.netflix.com/it/

That's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
while True:
    driver.get("https://www.netflix.com/it/")
    login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".authLinks.signupBasicHeader")
    login.click()
    element = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
    element.send_keys("test1@email.com")
    submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.login-button.btn-submit.btn-small")
    submit.click()
    element2 = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    element2.send_keys("test1")
    submit.click()
```

But sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and it raises this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netflix.py", line 35, in <module>
    submit.click()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 72, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 461, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///tmp/tmp7otgskq8/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///tmp/tmp7otgskq8/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmp7otgskq8/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmp7otgskq8/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmp7otgskq8/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

The exception says that a part of the web page is invisible (even if that part IS in the page actually)... It's a sort of bug.
How can I bypass this?

Comment: add a `wait` after opening the url, to give the driver some time in order to display the element.

Comment: I added a time.sleep but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

No need to put the test code inside `while` loop, since login form should be submitted once. I guess when it works successfully, next iteration gives error since there is no form.

You are also clicking the submit button before and after password entry. It is better to click after form is fully filled, if possible and not testing empty form.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.netflix.com/it/")
login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".authLinks.signupBasicHeader")
login.click()
element = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
element.send_keys("test1@email.com")
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.login-button.btn-submit.btn-small")
submit.click()
element2 = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
element2.send_keys("test1")
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.login-button.btn-submit.btn-small")
submit.click()
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I need while True because in the real and full script (i posted just the submit part where there is the exception) I try to login with several accounts. so i need while loop. And about the submit, I wrote it 2 times cause the netflix login page sometimes opens a form with email and password in the same page, and sometimes it displays: first the email form, and there is a submit button that takes to password input, and then to submit of ALL form (email and password) an example is here: http://imgur.com/a/4lGf6

Comment: if you want to test with different users you should write a login function and call it with different data in a case.

Comment: @AllExJ you can start by being polite.

Comment: Have I been impolite? If yes, I'm sorry, I'm not english.